# How to get full value of clob while debugging PL SQL script on sql developer

Tags: debugging, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm going in debug in a procedure PL/SQL on SQL Developer that make a big query and store it in a CLOB. When i take the value of that CLOB, the value is truncated. Can anyone know any method to take a full value of CLOB in debug mode?

Comment: Truncate length is 1300 and not 4000 (Max of varchar in Oracle). There is no errors in the procedure

Answer (score 1):

This procedure should help you, if I understood correctly you want to print the full value of clob?

```
PROCEDURE PRINT_CLOB(par_clob IN CLOB) IS
   ln_offset NUMBER DEFAULT 1;
BEGIN
 LOOP
  EXIT WHEN ln_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(par_clob);
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(par_clob, 255, ln_offset));
  ln_offset := ln_offset + 255;
 END LOOP;
END PRINT_CLOB;
```

Comment: Is a solution but i need  a solution directly on SQL Developer debug mode.

Comment: @Milaci did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

May be this might not be the answer you are looking for but in my application I have created a dummy table with column data type as clob. So whenever I want to get the value I will insert into this temporary table.

Comment: I do the same in my case. I don't think that is a solution directly on SQL Developer debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gregorianisch answer, I made my own version, which simply takes into account a carriage return to calculate the next chunk, to not cut any message (I needed to print query statements)

```
PROCEDURE print_clob(
    input_string IN CLOB
)
IS

    out_string_in CLOB default input_string;
    clob_length NUMBER := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(out_string_in);
    v_offset NUMBER default 0;
    v_chunk_size NUMBER := 32767;
    v_substr CLOB;

BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);

    WHILE v_offset < clob_length
    LOOP

        v_chunk_size := 32767;
        v_substr := SUBSTR(out_string_in, v_offset + 1, v_chunk_size);
        v_chunk_size := CASE WHEN INSTR(v_substr, CHR(10), -1) > 0 THEN INSTR(v_substr, CHR(10), -1) ELSE 32767 END;
        v_substr := SUBSTR(out_string_in, v_offset + 1, v_chunk_size);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_substr);
        v_offset := v_offset + v_chunk_size;

    END LOOP;

END print_clob;
```